# How do I get the correct view height in viewDidLayoutSubviews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, viewdidlayoutsubviews

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    NSLog(@"viewDidLayoutSubviews view.height: %f", self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```

In the above, `view.height` is *always* 1024 regardless of what orientation the device is in. Even rotating the device will cause `viewDidLayoutSubviews` to be called, and it will still output 1024.

Yet the view renders fine. What the heck am I missing?

Comment: What do you expect the height to be?

Comment: How do you get view.height?  Do you have a category on UIView?  Which view/view controller is this?  Is this your root view controller?

Comment: @SimonGoldeen Sorry yes, forgot to resolve that. It's defined in terms of the frame. Yes it is the root view controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When iOS performs an automatic rotation, it does not change the `frame` property of the root view controller's view.  What it does is apply a transform and animate the transform change.  To see the "actual" size of your view, check the `bounds` property instead of the `frame` property.

To quote [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html) of the `transform` property:

> Warning: If this property is not the identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

Comment: Thank you! That seems a very bizarre choice of design. Am I to presume this is *only* the case on the root view controller?

Comment: @chaiguy if you apply a transform to one of your views, the same thing will happen.  Its frame will no longer necessarily reflect its size or position.  With regard to why Apple does it this way, it is because the rotation animation is achieved through animating the transform change (Or so I assume).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's time to update in iOS8. In iOS8:

- UIScreen is now interface oriented:
- [UIScreen bounds] now interface-oriented
- [UIScreen applicationFrame] now interface-oriented
- Status bar frame notifications are interface-oriented
- Keyboard frame notifications are interface-oriented