# How to call drawRect after an orientation rotation animation is completed

Tags: ios, animation, orientation, drawrect

I am trying to use drawRect to draw a rectangle in the space below a collectionView contained in another view (self in the code below) using the frames of both views to define the rectangle.

This code works fine until the device orientation changes.  Everything I have tried calls drawRect before the animated rotation begins. This means the collectionView.frame and self.frame have not yet been adjusted by autoLayout and the resulting rectangle is wrong.

```
CGRect frame = self.collectionViwOutlet.frame;
CGFloat x = frame.origin.x;
CGFloat y = frame.origin.y + frame.size.height + 8;
CGFloat w = frame.size.width;
CGFloat h = self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height - y - 8;
CGRect drawableRect = CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2526162/1402846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your custom UIView override there `layoutSubviews`, which will be called for you by the system only when needed and when all the variables (orientation, size, etc.)

PS.: Consider it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19505582/846780

Comment: Thank you.  This explains the problem.  I'm still looking for a way around this.